# Load all data at once or bit by bit?

Tags: javascript, server

I'm building a tagging system where users can click and load more related tags.

Would it be more efficient to send every tag (1000 - 2000 rows) and filter client-side via JS. Or would it be better to send an initial set of tags, when a user clicks on a tag, we hit the server and load their related tags, and then they click another tag, server hit, user gets more tags etc.

Would it be better to send a large set of data just once, or continue to hit the server 3-6 times but overall send less data?

Comment: How many MB is every tag put together?

Comment: It is less than 1mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends**

Well, lets assume that have a 200ms ping, we can download 1MB a second (a 8 megabit link), and the data is 800kb. Then if we download the whole lot we take the total of a second waiting for the server. If instead we have 3-6 tiny requests we take a total of 600ms to 1200ms on ping times alone.

With this estimate it isn't clear which is better. Different clients will have different stats, perhaps resulting in some preferring each option.  I don't think we'd really know without some from of benchmark.

Another option would be to have a small request to start with and the precache the remaining values.

This has only considered time. Bandwidth can cost you and your clients money, multiple small requests would probably be cheaper.